# How to combine row based on column's value that is distinct in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my first post here.

My question is, how to combine row when timestamp (base on date only Y-m-d), item_condition and equipment_spare_id are same. Then GROUP_CONCAT remark and serial_number.

In this case, it should has 2 row.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post the expected result as table.

Comment: Sure. I will will update it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `group by`.  You are not clear on what the result set should look like, but the idea is:

```
select date(timestamp) as dte, item_condition, equipment_spare_id,
       count(*)
from t
group by dte, item_condition, equipment_spare_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` as follows:

```
SELECT 
    date(timestamp) as dte, 
    item_condition, 
    equipment_spare_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(remark) all_remarks,
    GROUP_CONCAT(serial_number) all_serials
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 
    date(timestamp), 
    item_condition, 
    equipment_spare_id
```